# open javascript library to do the same thing as symbolset

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts, symbols, opentype

I was planning on creating my own symbol font for use on my website and I had initially intended on using ligatures and OT but support is spotty at best, and non-existant for older browsers, especially IE (I know, big surprise). I then started taking a close look at how [SymbolSet](https://symbolset.com) works. It's actually pretty clever and while it would be easy for me to change a couple array variables and be done with it, the javascript is proprietary and I can't use it without permission. I'd love to be able to create my own symbol fonts a la SymbolSet but I'd need an open javascript file to let me do this. Are there any open jQuery plug-ins or javascript libraries that do this?

Comment: You mean you want ligatures, you want symbols on your website renderd with a font, or you want ligatures in order to have text that displays like an icon, but is still copy-pastetable?

Comment: I would love to use ligatures straight up but IE9 and older doesn't support them and some browsers have issues with them as well.

Comment: **Ignore the above comment, I can't edit it anymore.**

The latter. I would love to use ligatures straight up but IE9 and older doesn't support them and some browsers have issues with them as well. SymbolSet uses javascript to take icons stored in the private unicode section of an OTF file so older browsers that can't deal with ligatures would still be able to match the same keyword you're using for your ligatures. For instance, I might have a ligature for email (e_m_a_i_l.liga) and a private unicode character (u+2709) with the .js file linking 'email' to 'u+2709' through an array.

Comment: Actually symbolset still needs @font-face, so it only works on IE >= 9.

Comment: Symbolset provides EOT files so it does work with older versions of IE. All I really care about for this site is IE9+ but ligature support is non-existant in IE9 so I need a .js solution similar to SymbolSet. Which is where this originally started. Is there an open js library that does the same thing?

Comment: You seem to be right. The symbolset page didn't work on older IEs, I assumed it was because of lack of `@font-face` support. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this http://labs.adamdscott.com/ligatures/ligaturejs.html. Basically it walks the dom, and replaces the known letter combinations with ligatures. I've modified the script to use native ligature support when available:

```
// ligature.js v1.0
// http://code.google.com/p/ligature-js/

// with modifications by sabof

var ligature = (function() {
  var testDiv = document.createElement('div'), 
      nativeLigatureSupport = testDiv.style.textRendering !== undefined;
  if (nativeLigatureSupport) {
    return function (node, extended) {
      if (!node) {
        ligature(document.body, extended);
      } else {
        node.style.textRendering = 'optimizeLegibility';
      }
    }
  }
  return function(node, extended) {
    if (!node) {
      ligature(document.body, extended);
    } else {
      if (node.nodeType == 3 && node.parentNode.nodeName != 'SCRIPT') {
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue
          .replace(/ffl/g, 'ﬄ')
          .replace(/ffi/g, 'ﬃ')
          .replace(/fl/g, 'ﬂ')
          .replace(/fi/g, 'ﬁ')
          .replace(/ff/g, 'ﬀ')
          .replace(/ij/g, 'ĳ')
          .replace(/IJ/g, 'Ĳ');

        if (extended) {
          node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue
            .replace(/ae/g, 'æ')
            .replace(/A[Ee]/g, 'Æ')
            .replace(/oe/g, 'œ')
            .replace(/O[Ee]/g, 'Œ')
            .replace(/ue/g, 'ᵫ')
            .replace(/st/g, 'ﬆ');
        }
      }
      if (node.childNodes) {
        for (var i=0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
          ligature(node.childNodes.item(i), extended);
        }
      }
    }
  };

}());
```